# can't use DecimalFormat class within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, decimalformat

i am developing a blackberry project through the latest eclipse IDE. i am wanting to use the DecimalFormat class, however, i have noticed that eclipse doesn't recognize this class. Even if i change the JDK compliance level to 1.5, the project rebuilds fine but it still won't recognize it (so you still see the class underlines with red lines). Even if you were to attempt to import the class from the java.text package, eclipse doesn't recognize that package and simply says "the import java.text cannot be resolved".

so what am i doing wrong? or am i just stuck accepting the fact that a blackberry project will NEVER recognize certain java classes?

thank you in advance. good day.

ac

Answer (score 2):

DecimalFormat is not part of the BlackBerry API

[BlackBerry 4.5 API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/index.html)

You are going to need to use [MessageFormat](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/MessageFormat.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

Re-read my answer to your related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058845/can-you-integrate-java-1-6-classes-into-eclipse-blackberry-project/2059360#2059360).  J2ME is a subset of J2SE so there will be many classes missing, such as the DecimalFormat class.